# Use Paging in Source Data for Model in Freemarker-Template

Tags: spring, freemarker

*This is **NOT** about client-side paging in a browser!*

My problem is that I plan to generate a rather huge XML-file using Freemarker as the template engine. From my current knowledge this means that I need to feed the entire set of data into the model at once, which requires lots of RAM in the machine.

To avoid that I plan to read paged data from a database using spring-data [like so](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts). Using something like `Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);` should solve the part of getting the source data in smaller bits. But, what about generating the file?

Is there a way to use some sort of paging or to stream data to Freemarker?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement some sort of FreeMarker `TemplateModel`. For instance you could implement `TemplateMethodModelEx` to take a page as an argument and return your data. Theoretically this would work and FreeMarker renderer would invoke the method only when needed, but I haven't tested this kind of setup so can't be certain.

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry that I haven't replied yet, but don't worry, I'll look into it once I'm working on this part of the code again...